# Bigcommerce - request products based on a list of IDs

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using the [Bigcommerce API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api) to develop a small standalone application for a client. I store product information in a local database anytime I fetch products from Bigcommerce, to reduce latency and network load. However, products can change on Bigcommerce, and while it is acceptable for my application to show mildly outdated information, I will need to update my local cache at some point. My current plan is to do this by storing the original date I requested the product, after which I will need to perform another request to refresh the cache.

My question is, given a list of products (including their Bigcommerce IDs), is there a way to request updates to all of them through a single call to the [Products Resource](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products)? I can make a request for each individual product by calling:

```
GET {api}/v2/products/{id}
```

I can also request all products within an unbroken ID range by calling:

```
GET {api}/v2/products?min_id={value}&max_id={value}
```

I am able to successfully call both of the above methods, and I can chain them together in loops to fetch all products. What I want to do is request multiple products with unrelated IDs in a single call. So, something like this:

```
//THIS IS NOT A REAL METHOD!
GET {api}/v2/products?id[]={value1}&id[]={value2}
```

Is there any way I can do this? Or is there another approach to solving this that I haven't considered? My main requirements are:

1. Minimal API requests. My application is small but my client's bigcommerce store is not, and I will be processing tens of thousands of products. I have limited CPU and network resources available, and I simply cannot process that many requests.
2. Scalable. As I said, my client's store is large, and growing. I need a solution whose overhead scales at a manageable rate with number of products.

Note: my application is a small web application written in PHP running on a Linux shared hosting environment. It is a back of house system which will likely only be used by single user at a time, during standard business hours. I haven't tagged the question with PHP because my question is about the API, which is language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approch can be.

First get all products from BigCommerce using simple products call.

Set some interval time to get updated product list.

You can use `min_date_modified` and `max_date_modified` OR `min_date_created` and `max_date_created` in products API call to get updated products details.

Comment: This is not an ideal fit for my application, because I only care about updates to a subset of the products rather than all of the products. This is, however, a very good solution to most applications. I ultimately realized that the structure of my application permits me to simply drop old cached products as I will usually not need them again after that much time.

One addition I would make to your answer is that by combining `max_date_created` with `min_date_modified`, you can fetch only updated products, filtering out newly created products. That may be non-obvious but valuable to some.